# difficulties connecting to a EC2 instance via my win10 desktop and the aws console

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am self leaning for AWS solution architects exam.

I have created an EC2 instance.  From the AWS console page I select my instance.  I click connect, it takes me to the "connect to your instance" screen pop.  I select "EC2 Instance Connect (browser-based SSH connection)" but the bottom right Connect button will not work.

I am running the console page via my windows 10 laptop using the default Microsoft Edge browser.

Is there anything I need to change on my laptop to get the SSH connection or do I have a different problem?  Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the Security Group "Inbound" configuration.

Comment: Please also explain what you mean when you say *"the bottom right Connect button will not work."*  What does it do?

Answer (score 0):

Please validate it matches the [requirements](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-connect-methods.html):

> The following Linux distributions are supported:
>
> - Amazon Linux 2 (any version)
> - Ubuntu 16.04 or later
>
> To connect using the browser-based client, the instance must have a public IPv4 address.
>
> To connect using the EC2 Instance Connect CLI, your instance does not need to have a public IPv4 address because the private IP address can be used. If your instance has both a public and private IP address, the API first tries to connect using the public IP address.
>
> EC2 Instance Connect does not support connecting using an IPv6 address.
>
> The Safari browser is currently not supported.

Additionally make sure it has SSH access in the security group.